# How do I enable notifications and to be able read in my BLE code?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

So I have a scale which sends out weight data through BLE UUID 0xFFF4. It works with the app nRF Connect when I toggle notification on, I see the data.

However, I can't get it on my own app. I have code which reads characteristic data  of 0xFFF4 that I followed a tutorial to do, but I'm not sure how to set notification on 0xFFF4 and receive the data.

The code I modified and implemented is on the bottom, where the service is 0xFFF0 and the read is 0xFFF4. It works for any other characteristic read for the scale such as the name, but I can't get the weight data and I think it's because I have to set notifications on and I have no clue how to do that.

```
/**
* Service for managing connection and data communication with a GATT server hosted on a
* given Bluetooth LE device.
*/
public class BluetoothLeService extends Service {
private final static String TAG = BluetoothLeService.class.getSimpleName();

private BluetoothManager mBluetoothManager;
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private String mBluetoothDeviceAddress;
private BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt;
private int mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;

private static final int STATE_DISCONNECTED = 0;
private static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 1;
private static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 2;

public final static String ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED";
public final static String ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED";
public final static String ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED";
public final static String ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE";
public final static String EXTRA_DATA =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.EXTRA_DATA";

public final static UUID UUID_HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT =
        UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT);

// Implements callback methods for GATT events that the app cares about.  For example,
// connection change and services discovered.
private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        String intentAction;
        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            intentAction = ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED;
            mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTED;
            broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
            Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GATT server.");
            // Attempts to discover services after successful connection.
            Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to start service discovery:" +
                    mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices());

        } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
            intentAction = ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED;
            mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
            Log.i(TAG, "Disconnected from GATT server.");
            broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                     BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                     int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
    }
};

private void broadcastUpdate(final String action) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}

private void broadcastUpdate(final String action,
                             final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);

    // This is special handling for the Heart Rate Measurement profile.  Data parsing is
    // carried out as per profile specifications:
    // http://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.characteristic.heart_rate_measurement.xml
    if (UUID_HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
        int flag = characteristic.getProperties();
        int format = -1;
        if ((flag & 0x01) != 0) {
            format = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT16;
            Log.d(TAG, "Heart rate format UINT16.");
        } else {
            format = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8;
            Log.d(TAG, "Heart rate format UINT8.");
        }
        final int heartRate = characteristic.getIntValue(format, 1);
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("Received heart rate: %d", heartRate));
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, String.valueOf(heartRate));
    } else {
        // For all other profiles, writes the data formatted in HEX.
        final byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
        if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
            final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(data.length);
            for(byte byteChar : data)
                stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02X ", byteChar));
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, new String(data) + "\n" + stringBuilder.toString());
        }
    }
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    BluetoothLeService getService() {
        return BluetoothLeService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    // After using a given device, you should make sure that BluetoothGatt.close() is called
    // such that resources are cleaned up properly.  In this particular example, close() is
    // invoked when the UI is disconnected from the Service.
    close();
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}

private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

/**
 * Initializes a reference to the local Bluetooth adapter.
 *
 * @return Return true if the initialization is successful.
 */
public boolean initialize() {
    // For API level 18 and above, get a reference to BluetoothAdapter through
    // BluetoothManager.
    if (mBluetoothManager == null) {
        mBluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        if (mBluetoothManager == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to initialize BluetoothManager.");
            return false;
        }
    }

    mBluetoothAdapter = mBluetoothManager.getAdapter();
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to obtain a BluetoothAdapter.");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

/**
 * Connects to the GATT server hosted on the Bluetooth LE device.
 *
 * @param address The device address of the destination device.
 *
 * @return Return true if the connection is initiated successfully. The connection result
 *         is reported asynchronously through the
 *         {@code BluetoothGattCallback#onConnectionStateChange(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt, int, int)}
 *         callback.
 */
public boolean connect(final String address) {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || address == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized or unspecified address.");
        return false;
    }

    // Previously connected device.  Try to reconnect.
    if (mBluetoothDeviceAddress != null && address.equals(mBluetoothDeviceAddress)
            && mBluetoothGatt != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Trying to use an existing mBluetoothGatt for connection.");
        if (mBluetoothGatt.connect()) {
            mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
    if (device == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Device not found.  Unable to connect.");
        return false;
    }
    // We want to directly connect to the device, so we are setting the autoConnect
    // parameter to false.
    mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);
    Log.d(TAG, "Trying to create a new connection.");
    mBluetoothDeviceAddress = address;
    mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
    return true;
}

/**
 * Disconnects an existing connection or cancel a pending connection. The disconnection result
 * is reported asynchronously through the
 * {@code BluetoothGattCallback#onConnectionStateChange(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt, int, int)}
 * callback.
 */
public void disconnect() {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
        return;
    }
    mBluetoothGatt.disconnect();
}

/**
 * After using a given BLE device, the app must call this method to ensure resources are
 * released properly.
 */
public void close() {
    if (mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        return;
    }
    mBluetoothGatt.close();
    mBluetoothGatt = null;
}

/**
 * Request a read on a given {@code BluetoothGattCharacteristic}. The read result is reported
 * asynchronously through the {@code BluetoothGattCallback#onCharacteristicRead(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt, android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic, int)}
 * callback.
 *
 * @param characteristic The characteristic to read from.
 */
public void readCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
        return;
    }
    mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
}

/**
 * Enables or disables notification on a give characteristic.
 *
 * @param characteristic Characteristic to act on.
 * @param enabled If true, enable notification.  False otherwise.
 */
public void setCharacteristicNotification(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                          boolean enabled) {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
        return;
    }
    mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, enabled);

    // This is specific to Heart Rate Measurement.
    if (UUID_HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
        BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(
                UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG));
        descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
        mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
    }
}

/**
 * Retrieves a list of supported GATT services on the connected device. This should be
 * invoked only after {@code BluetoothGatt#discoverServices()} completes successfully.
 *
 * @return A {@code List} of supported services.
 */
public List<BluetoothGattService> getSupportedGattServices() {
    if (mBluetoothGatt == null) return null;

    return mBluetoothGatt.getServices();
}

public void readCustomCharacteristic() {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
        return;
    }
    /*check if the service is available on the device*/
    BluetoothGattService mCustomService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID.fromString("0000fff0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
    if(mCustomService == null){
        Log.w(TAG, "Custom BLE Service not found");
        return;
    }
    /*get the read characteristic from the service*/
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic mReadCharacteristic = mCustomService.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("0000fff4-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
    if(mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(mReadCharacteristic) == false){
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read characteristic");
    }
}



}
```

I've been trying to get this to work for months, but BLE is just so difficult to understand and there's no easy guide to implementation, which is a big pain. If anyone could help out, it would be very much appreciated. Thank you very much.

Edit: I think I have to add

```
BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = mCustomService.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("0000fff4-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")).getDescriptor(
                UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG));
        descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
        mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
```

But it doesn't seem to work, I get errors. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is my `setNotifications()` method, which works fine in my code:

```
public void setNotifications() {
    BluetoothGattService service = bluetoothGatt.getService(SERVICE_UUID);
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = service.getCharacteristic(CHARACTERISTIC_UUID);

    BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(DESCRIPTOR_UUID);
    descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
    characteristic.addDescriptor(descriptor);
    characteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE);
    bluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);

    bluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);
}
```

Hope it helps.